# Case in a Where Clause

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

I'm new to SQL and I am trying to understand the CASE clause. I would like to print the department name in the report next to the Department code when counting the merchandise. Can you tell me what I am doing incorrectly. Thank you.

```
SELECT  
DEPT_C AS "DEPT CODE",
NAME as "DEPT NAME",
TO_CHAR(COUNT(*), '999,999,999,999') AS TOTAL 
FROM STORE.DEPT 
WHERE CASE  
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D01' THEN 'WOMAN ACTIVE WEAR' 
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D02' THEN 'WOMAN PLUS SIZE'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D03' THEN 'JUNIORS'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D04' THEN 'GIRLS'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D05' THEN 'INFANTS AND TODDLERS'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D06' THEN 'ACCESSORIES'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D07' THEN 'JEWLERY'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D08' THEN 'PERFUME'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D09' THEN 'COSMETICS'
ELSE 'OTHER' END NAME
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue was I had the case in the where and it should have been in the Select. I also fixed the group by. It works fine as follows:

Comment: SELECT  
    DEPT_C AS "DEPT CODE",
    (CASE  
    WHEN DEPT_C = 'D01' THEN 'WOMAN ACTIVE WEAR' 
    WHEN DEPT_C = 'D02' THEN 'WOMAN PLUS SIZE'
    WHEN DEPT_C = 'D03' THEN 'JUNIORS'
    WHEN DEPT_C = 'D04' THEN 'GIRLS'
    WHEN DEPT_C = 'D05' THEN 'INFANTS AND TODDLERS'
    WHEN DEPT_C = 'D06' THEN 'ACCESSORIES'
    WHEN DEPT_C = 'D07' THEN 'JEWLERY'
    WHEN DEPT_C = 'D08' THEN 'PERFUME'
    WHEN DEPT_C = 'D09' THEN 'COSMETICS' 
    ELSE 'OTHER' END) DEPT_NAME,
    TO_CHAR(COUNT(*), '999,999,999,999') AS TOTAL 
    FROM STORE.DEPT 
    GROUP BY DEPT_C
    ORDER BY 2,1;

Answer (score 3):

Think of `CASE` as a `switch` statement.

In this case, you want a different name for each department code. Therefore your cases use the `DEPT_C` column as the reference variable, and assign name values for individual codes.

Like this:

```
SELECT  
DEPT_C AS "DEPT CODE",
CASE DEPT_C
WHEN 'D01' THEN 'WOMAN ACTIVE WEAR' 
WHEN 'D02' THEN 'WOMAN PLUS SIZE'
WHEN 'D03' THEN 'JUNIORS'
WHEN 'D04' THEN 'GIRLS'
WHEN 'D05' THEN 'INFANTS AND TODDLERS'
WHEN 'D06' THEN 'ACCESSORIES'
WHEN 'D07' THEN 'JEWLERY'
WHEN 'D08' THEN 'PERFUME'
WHEN 'D09' THEN 'COSMETICS'
ELSE 'OTHER' 
END as 'DEPT NAME'
FROM STORE.DEPT
```

**EDIT:**

You can also ignore the `input expression`, namely the `DEPT_C`, but then each condition should be explicit, like this:

```
SELECT  
DEPT_C AS "DEPT CODE",
CASE 
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D01' THEN 'WOMAN ACTIVE WEAR' 
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D02' THEN 'WOMAN PLUS SIZE'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D03' THEN 'JUNIORS'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D04' THEN 'GIRLS'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D05' THEN 'INFANTS AND TODDLERS'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D06' THEN 'ACCESSORIES'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D07' THEN 'JEWLERY'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D08' THEN 'PERFUME'
WHEN DEPT_C = 'D09' THEN 'COSMETICS'
ELSE 'OTHER' 
END as 'DEPT NAME'
FROM STORE.DEPT
```

**CAVEAT:**
**I changed your select order, be sure to rewrite your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` accordingly.**